# How to initiate an $apply from outside of angular

Tags: angularjs, apply

I have a button that increments a counter. The count is displayed from within the Angular world, while the button is outside the Angular world. I can get the value into the angular world by making it global (yeah, ugly), but how do I then get some Angular code to use $apply to update it's $digest cycle? (based on an that click event)

BTW: I know I could use ng-click to bring the click event into Angular, but out of curiosity I'd like to know how to solve this without doing that.

Here's the plnk:
https://plnkr.co/edit/UTElTmggj3ae2c19bsL1?p=preview

```
var gCounter = 0;

$(function() {

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  console.log('click!')
  gCounter++;
})

});


(function() {

  var app = angular.module('app', []);
  var ctrl = app.controller('ctrl', Ctrl);


  function Ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return gCounter
    }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
      $scope.counter = newVal;
    });

  }

}

 }());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the scope associated to the clicked button, and then call `$apply()` using

```
$(this).scope().$apply();
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Your solution has been applied to the plunker.